# Continuity at any point using polar co-ordinate

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, polar-coordinates

I had the following questions in one of my exercises

> Determine if the following function is continuous
> $$ f(x,y)=
> \begin{cases} 
>  \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
>  0 & (x,y) = (0,0)
>    \end{cases}      
>   $$

The answer to this is **No** since the limit doesn't exist at $(0,0)$, but to explain the continuity of this function at points other than the origin, my instructor used the polar form function to showcase that the function is well-defined and so is continuous.

The polar form of this function is
$$f(r,\theta) = \sin2\theta $$
He said that since the polar function is well-defined everywhere except for $0$ (perhaps he meant origin I guess) we can say that the function is continuous everywhere except for $0$.
The question I've is

1. Why the function is not well-defined at the origin?
2. How can we determine continuity at any point using polar form?

Comment: That is not a very good argument. Every function is well defined, and that does not imply continuity. However, its true that any rational function and trigonometric function is continuous on its domain, so he probably was eliding some details. Personally it isn't any more clear that $\sin(2\theta)$ is continuous compared to $\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$ away from the origin.

Comment: First, the "polar" function is not well-defined at the origin because it fails to give a single value at $r = 0$ due to the angular-only dependence in polar coordinates. And second, the continuity of the "polar" function away from the origin implies the continuity of the original function because the transformation between these coordinates, *in* $\mathbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus \{(0,0)\},$ is bijective and continuous both ways. But in this case, arguing by change of coordinates is pointless since the original function is clearly continuous away from the origin.

Comment: What you *can* do with this "trick" of passing to polar coordinates is argue that $f$ is not continuous at the origin. If $f$ were to be continuous at $(0,0)$, the value $f(0,0)$ should be the limit of the "polar" version of $f$ as $r \rightarrow 0^+.$ But this does not give a single value, therefore it's impossible to define $f$ at the origin in a continuous way.

Comment: @Edd no it is not continuous both ways, especially since you’re taking $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$. One needs to remove an infinite closed half ray emanating from the origin to get the homeomorphism/diffeomorphism. But yea, this just goes to show that changing to polar coordinates is a very poor way of justifying continuity (atleast for 99% of the problems I’ve seen on the site).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oops, I'm sorry. I had a serious tunnel vision about the problems at the origin and forgot the usual continuity-problems that the angular coordinate carries. The "polar" argument can still be made (with more care) to prove that $f$ cannot be continuously defined at the origin, but I agree that it's better to avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: sure the argument is fixable (choosing two coordinate charts which together cover the entire punctured plane to prove continuity away from the origin, and that there is no continuous extension to the origin) but yea, it’s just not worth the hassle.